# Multilabel Classification: Accuracy is very low. Metric or Model, which is inadequate?

Tags: model-evaluation, accuracy, keras, sparse, multilabel

In my multilabel classifaction problem, which I approach similarly to what can be see in this post: [How does Keras handle multilabel classification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164749/how-does-keras-handle-multilabel-classification), the resulting accuracy only increases from 2% to 5%. There are 28 different classes in the target vector. One example vector:

```
[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,...0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

(Note that the given data is very sparse, meaning we have far more 0 values that 1 values.)

In a normal single label binary classification problem, I would interpret this performance as a strong hint that the model is inadequate. Here, however, I am not sure what values for accuracy I am supposed to expect in the first place. Does anybody have suggestion on that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should select your performance metrics first. Have a look at Hemming score for instance.

Comment: @Nathan did you mean "Hamming loss"? "Hemming Score" does not seem to exist.

Comment: [*Accuracy* is already problematic as an evaluation measure.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) Besides, see [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222179/1352) I don't think we can diagnose your specific problem without a lot more information.